# Subida fichero mediante ajax con mas de un parámetro

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, web

necesito subir un fichero con ajax en mi aplicación web con django en el servidor. El problema está en que necesito enviar mas de un parámetro al servidor y no sé que tipo de dato configurar en la instrucción ajax

## Cliente

```
    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "/Incidencia/uploadFile/",
                        processData:false,
                        contentType : false,
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        headers : {
                            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
                        },
                        data: {
                            file:$(currentInput).val(),
                            CodigoAuto:$("#id_CodigoAuto").val(),
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            $(currentInput).parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-spinner").removeClass("fa-spin").addClass("fa-check");
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            $(currentInput).parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-spinner").removeClass("fa-spin").addClass("fa-exclamation-triangle");
                        },
```

## Server

```
def uploadFile(request):
    print request.POST
    fil = request.POST.get("file")
```

Según la consola del servidor de pruebas de django la el objeto request llega vacío. Los parámetros del json los he puesto con y sin comillas por que en internet lo he encontrado de las dos formas pero no me funciona de ninguna.
Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Los archivos se encuentran en `request.FILES` y no en `request.POST`

Comment: Ya, pero no estoy pasando un único parámetro en la petición sino un json con el fichero en su interior. En otros casos si que he pillado los datos desde request.FILES pero al hacerlo de este modo pensé que sería distinto. De todos modos tal y como comentas tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problemas

1. Estás enviando los archivos en formato JSON, cuando un fichero se envía en forma binaria. Puedes enviar un archivo binario en un JSON si lo conviertes a [`Base64`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

   ```
   data: {
     file: $(currentInput).val(),
     CodigoAuto:$("#id_CodigoAuto").val(),
   }
   ```
2. Estás enviando **la ruta falsa del fichero** más no el fichero en sí. Los archivos se almacenan en la propiedad `files`.

   ```
   file: $(currentInput).val() // /home/fakepath/fichero.xyz
   ```

Así no obtendrás el archivo en `request.FILES` (ni el equivalente en cualquier lenguaje).

#### Soluciones

1. Una solución sencilla es enviar un [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)¹ con el archivo y los datos que se quiera.

   ```
   let data = new FormData();
   data.append('file', currentInput.files[0]);
   data.append('codigoAuto', $('#id_CodigoAuto').val());
   ```

   De tal modo que envías dicho objeto en lugar de un JSON:

   ```
   {
     ...
     data: data
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Enviar el archivo en `Base64` usando [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)² para su conversión.

   ```
   function fileToBase64(file, cb) {
     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function () {
       cb(reader.result);
     };
   }
   ```

---

¹ si usas la opción `contentType` to false no necesitas agregar el tipo de la data mediante `enctype`.

² compatible com IE 10+, Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 7+, Safari 6.0.2+.